# Minimize sum function after finding its derivative

Tags: optimization, summation, maxima-minima

According to the exercise I am making, the function $L = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - b)^2$ should be minimized for $b = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i}$.

I have figured out that for $y_j$ with $j = 3$, this is the case:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y_3} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}*((y_1-b)^2+(y_2-b)^2+(y_3-b)^2+...+(y_n-b)^2)}{y_3} = \frac{1}{n}*2(y_3-b)$

So I thought I could conclude that: $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} = \frac{1}{n}*2(y_3-b)$

In this case, if $y_j = b$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} = 0$. Now I think I have found the extrema, but how do I find the minimum of function L?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at your result it seems that you have to minimize L w.r.t. parameter $b$. In this case you differentiate $L$ and set it equal to zero. We have to apply the chain rule when differentiating the squared brackets.

$$\frac{dL}{db}=2\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - b)\cdot (-1)=0$$

We can omit the constants $2$ and $(-1)$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - b)=0$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = \sum_{i=1}^nb$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: But why can you conclude the last step from the second-last step?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y_i - b)=0$ Every summand gets his own sigma sign. $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^nb=0$. Adding $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb$ on both sides gives $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i =\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb$

Comment: And you left out the $\frac{1}{n}$ from L in the first step, but if you omit the constants 2 and -1, do you need to do that with $\frac{1}{n}$ too? Or do you put that in front of the sum function in your last line at the end?

Comment: @Julius The reasoning for the factors $(-1)$ and $2$ are different from the case 1/n. **1)** If you have a constant c and a function f(x) then maximizing $c\cdot f(x)$ is the same as maximizing $f(x)$. **2)** If you have an equation $c\cdot g(x)=0$, with $c\neq 0$, then you can omit c since it cannot get $0$ and thus $g(x)$ must be $0$.

Comment: okay, but I am struggling with how I can proceed, because I still need to find b instead of $\sum_{i=1}^n{b}$. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: What is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb$? Note: b does not depend on index i.

Comment: That is just b+b+b+...+b

Comment: @Julius Yes, $n$ times $b$ thus $n\cdot b$. Then divide the equation by $n$. Then you get the expression for $b$ which minimizes $L$

Comment: Ah I have found the answer, thank you so much!

Comment: @Julius That pleases me. You´re welcome.